# Proper way to use an url in the action attribute of a form in wordpress

Tags: html, forms, url

I have a custom form in one of my wordpress pages(this page uses a custom template)-

```
       <form action="www.mysite.com/custom-page-2" method="post">
                    . 
                    .
                    .
       </form>
```

Now the problem is that on submitting the browser shows the url "www.mysite.com/custom-page-2" in the address bar but shows a 404 page not found error.
I read other solutions which ask to use action attribute for the same form page or use ajax or jquery. But my question is that why cant we use this method like normal php.
What am I missing?

Comment: I think you forgot the "http://". The url must be "http://www.mysite.com/custom-page-2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is if you use general values for your "name" attribute it surprisingly fails(example- name="name")...just prefix it with some unique name...maybe wordpress uses these names itself and causes clashes..

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the action to: `http://www.mysite.com/custom-page-2`

**UPDATE**

After a little bit of digging it seems you need to set your action to an empty string, and redirect to the page you want during the form submission handler.

Try following steps 1 - 3 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137105/wordpress-form-action-submit) but instead of redirecting back to the same page, redirect to the page you want to go to.

Hope that helps

Comment: i wish the soln had been so simple ;| ...tried every possible combination...it has something to do with the way wordpress handles the request urls...

Comment: Seems Wordpress form handling is a bit weird, I've updated the answer above with some more info

Comment: I had read the answer u mentioned...just thought someone might know why it has to be this way and not the way I have asked...